# Migrating an On Premise solution to Azure

Tags: azure, xenapp

I have an on premise solution that consists of a server (1 machine) and X users (each in 1 machine). All the users are using the same Win32 application. The question is: How do I translate this in to an Azure enviroment? Each of the users machines are using 4 CPUs and 8 GB of RAM (this is necessary).

Do I have to configure a new machine which has to have the 4 CPUs and 8GB per user, or is there a more efficient way to get this done? Because otherwhise this is not economically profitable.

I was thinking about using XenApp and only one VM for all the users to solve this problem. But I'm not quite sure.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

you could automate the provisioning of the VMs with ARM templates. Your virtualizationception could also work. But then: how do you garantee the 8GB of RAM that is necessary? Would be good to have some more details about the requirements.